# Accessing PostgreSQL (on wsl2) from DBeaver (on Windows) fails: "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: postgresql, wsl-2

What I'm trying is to use Postgres and access it from DBeaver.

- Postgres is installed into wsl2 (Ubuntu 20)
- DBeaver is installed into Windows 10

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking), if you access an app running on Linuc from Windows, `localhost` can be used.

However...

[image]

Connection is refused with `localhost`. Also, I don't know what this message means: `Connection refused: connect`.

Does anyone see potential cause for this? Any advice will be appreciated.

Note:

- The password should be fine. When I use `psql` in wsl2 and type in the password, `psql` is available with the password
- I don't have Postgres on Windows' side. It exists only on wsl2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

I just had to allow the TCP connection on wsl2(Ubuntu) and then restart postgres.

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
# You should see "Rules updated" and/or "Rules updated (v6)"
sudo service postgresql restart
```

I didn't change IPv4/IPv6 connections info. Here's what I see in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Then you should go ahead and accept your own answer.  That lets future questioners with the same issue know there was s successful answer. It also removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not let successfully answered question remain as unanswered.

Comment: @Belayer Yeah I will. SO doesn't allow me to accept my own answer immediately. I have to wait for one day

Comment: I'm still unable to connect to my Dbeaver in window 10 after running the cmd `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp` in my WSL2...

Comment: @Hugo1280 running into the same issue, any fixes?

Comment: @MayukhNair follow the instruction from this article: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-on-wsl2-for-windows-install-and-setup/
if still not working, then try using `md5` instead of `scram-sha-256` as mentioned in the article.

Comment: After allowing `5432/tcp` I had to use `wsl --shutdown` (outside of WSL) before I could connect.

Answer (score 2):

same problem i solved.
By the way some explanation :
WSL runs as a Docker.
Inside wsl, localhost is valid for the app running in wsl.
Outside , in windows, localhost is valid for app running in windows.
First manner : install dbeaver under WSL and run it from there: localhost as 'host' will be found.
Second manner : if you have installed dbeaver (or pgadmin4 in my case ) on windows, you must use **the adress of the docker on win**.
To find it :

```bash
ip addr show eth0   -> inet 172.21.35.114
```

Add this address to your **pg_hba.conf**

```
      host    all             all             172.21.35.114/32        md5
      host    all             all             172.21.32.1/32          md5
```

The second IP is the link between WSL and WIN.  I got it when i start dbeaver from win that tells me this one was also missing.